# React Router - Navigating to same route results in re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi i'm not sure whether this is a desired behaviour or a bug.

This is an empty create-react-app example with `react-router-dom`

Versions:

- "react": "^16.13.1",
- "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
- "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
- "react-scripts": "3.4.1"

There are two routes under the `Switch` component:

1. /         - for Home component
2. /contacts - for Contacts component

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    
    class Home extends React.PureComponent {
      render() {
        console.log("Home rendered");
        return <h1>Homepage</h1>;
      }
    }
    
    //const HomeMemo = React.memo(Home);
    //const Home = () => <h1>Homepage</h1>;
    const Contacts = () => <h1>Contacts</h1>;
    
    const Header = () => {
      console.log("Header Render");
      return (
        <header className="App-header">
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <br />
          <Link to="/contacts">Contacts</Link>
        </header>
      );
    };
    
    function App() {
      console.log("App Render");
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Fiddle available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sinoussi-y0l4f?file=/src/App.js:0-889)

Clicking on Home link multiple times results in a `Home rendered` message.

My assuption was that if we're already on same route it would not attempt to re-render?

Comment: where and how did you see that  cliking on home link, the page is re-rendering?

Comment: @AskMen see the Console log at the bottom left of the Browser tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have raised an associated Github ticket [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7539)

And was told by a community member that this is **By-Design**

The reasons for this design decision remains unknown.